Quantum non-demolition condition in Breuer
I am reading "The Theory of Open Quantum Systems" by Francesco Petruccione and Heinz-Peter Breuer and came across this condition for non-demolition measurements (eq 2.237),
$$ \sum_m \text{Tr}\{\Omega_m^\dagger[A^k,\Omega_m]\rho\}=0,$$
where the $\Omega_m$ represent the characteristic operators of the measurement scheme, and $A$ the operator with respect to which we are considering the non-demolition nature. Here, this condition is assumed to hold for all $\rho$ and $k$. Now, as per the definition earlier, it seems the more appropriate condition should be
$$\sum_m \text{Tr}\{\Omega_m^\dagger[\Pi_a,\Omega_m]\rho\}=0,$$
where $\Pi_a$ represents all the spectral projectors of our operator because the condition explicitly states the distribution doesn't change, and only demanding the commutation of the moments would exclude those distributions where such moments don't exist.
Nonetheless, proceeding along the book's lines, they arrive at the much stronger yet sufficient condition
$$[\Omega_m,A]=0 \quad\forall m. \quad (1)$$
However, doing the analogous move with the corrected condition, we get
$$[\Omega_m,\Pi_a]=0 \quad\forall m,a. \quad (2)$$
(2) seems much stronger than (1), and in fact (1) does not seem sufficient for the corrected requirement in a non-demolition measurement. The proceeding parts in the book seem to rely on the condition using $A,$ so it seems vital it takes that form even though it is insufficient, but maybe I am missing some sense in which (1) implies (2)?
Am I missing something here?
